# Add text and an alligned image to a ColumnText Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am writing text from right to left.

how can i add an image at the end of the text (alligned nicely)?

Comment: where are you writing? how do you write?

Comment: @elyashiv   I am writing to a pdf file. I know how to add images, but the question is how can add an image so it will show in the end of a text. I can add a Paragraph to a document and then an image but it wont appear one after the other.

Comment: Please provide (boiled down) sample code of what you currently do and a description of what exactly is not nice in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't entirely clear.

The order of objects added to a Document is always respected, except in the case of `Image` objects. If an `Image` object doesn't fit the page, it can be forwarded to the next page, and other content can be added first. If you want to avoid this, use `writer.setStrictImageSequence(true)`;

However: you're writing from Right to Left (probably in Hebrew), so the above doesn't apply, not the previous answer by Anshu. You can only use RTL in `ColumnText` and `PdfPTable`.

It's not clear what you want to do.

Do you want to add an `Image` at the bottom of the text? That's easy: just add the text first, then add the `Image`. Do you want to add an `Image` inline? In that case, you can wrap the `Image` in a `Chunk` as is done in this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=54

My interpretation is: you want to add the image at the bottom left, and you want the text to be added next to the image. That's more difficult to achieve. You'd need to add the `Image` and the text separately. Add the Image at an absolute position and add the text using 'irregular columns'. That is: `ColumnText` in text mode (as opposed to composite mode). For an example showing how to use irregular columns, see http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=67

Comment: Thanks for your ongoing support fot the itext package (after all you are the author :))