# Align content in PDF using itext in java

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

I am stuck up with this problem for sometime now. I'm drawing a `pie chart` to the document and displaying the `jtable data`. I am not able to `align` the contents in the `pdf file`. How do I align the `jtable data` as well as the `pie chart` to this `pdf`. I have mentioned my `code` below with an `image`. [image]
As you can see, I need to align my `jtable data` a little to the top, and also it has to fit the `width` of the `page`.

```
     private void graphical_to_pdf() {

    graph_table.setSize(graph_table.getPreferredSize());

    JTableHeader th = graph_table.getTableHeader();
    th.setSize(th.getPreferredSize());

    PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 800, 800, 0.65f);
    com.itextpdf.text.Font f = new com.itextpdf.text.Font(com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18.0f, com.itextpdf.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

    Document doc = new Document(new com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle(900, 900));

    //Creating a paper to store the jtable contents
    Paper paper = new Paper();

    paper.setSize(800, 800);
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 100, 800, 800);

    PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
    pf.setPaper(paper);
    Printable printable = graph_table.getPrintable(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, null, null);

    try {
        PdfWriter writer;
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(save_pdf.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile() + ".pdf"));

        writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage);
        doc.open();
        int width = 375;
        int height = 300;

        JFreeChart chart = create_pie_chart_count();

        doc.add(new Paragraph("Some TExt", f));
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Some Text", f));
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Document Generated On - " + generatedDate, f));
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = chart.createBufferedImage(width, height);

        Image image = Image.getInstance(writer, bufferedImage, 1.0f);
        image.scalePercent(100f);
        image.setAlignment(image.MIDDLE);
        doc.add(image);
        PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer);
        writer.setOpenAction(action);

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

        int page = 0;

        int result = Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        do {
            result = printable.print(g, pf, page);
            if (result == Printable.PAGE_EXISTS) {
                cb.saveState();
                Graphics2D g2 = cb.createGraphics(650, 225);
                result = printable.print(g2, pf, page);
                g2.dispose();
                cb.restoreState();
                page++;
                doc.newPage();

            }

        } while (result == Printable.PAGE_EXISTS);
        g.dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answer to the following question: [How to position a PDFGraphis2D object in iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024681/how-to-position-a-pdfgraphis2d-object-in-itext)

As you can see, it is common *not* to draw objects such as the chart or the table straight to the direct content. Instead, you should create a `PdfTemplate` to draw to. One of the benefits of using a `PdfTemplate` is that you can wrap it inside an `Image`. Don't worry: if the `PdfTemplate` contains vector data, the `Image` will be a vector image; it won't be rasterized (which would lead to a loss of resolution).

Once you have `Image` objects, there are many different options to resize, position, organize them. You can get an idea of the different options when reading the answer to the following questions:

- [How to display image and text beside each other Itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780258/how-to-display-image-and-text-beside-each-other-itext)
- [itextsharp images are not coming next to one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700549/itextsharp-images-are-not-coming-next-to-one-another)
- [Add text and an alligned image to a ColumnText Itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883122/add-text-and-an-alligned-image-to-a-columntext-itext)
- ...

Comment: Well, that did help. I had to change the complete thing and it worked fine. But I never used any `PdfTemplate`. Instead, just fetched the data from my `jtable` and added that to the `PdfCell`. Thanks  :)